# Can I keep a separate set of key bindings for each of my machines?

Tags: diablo-iii

Keeping true to its online nature, I've noticed that Diablo III stores my selected keybindings in my account, so that I have the same bindings available whether I play on my desktop or my Macbook.

However, this is opposite of what I want. My desktop has a 5-button mouse and it would be a shame not to use all of them, but such keybindings will not translate well to my Macbook, where I use a simple 3-button mouse.

Is there any way to not synchronize my keybindings across machines, or to keep multiple "sets" of keybindings that are easily swappable?

Answer (score 2):

While it is maybe not the ideal solution, you could define "Key 1" for your desktop and "Key 2" for your Mac.  As long as your key definitions do not contradict between the two builds, I believe this will be workable.  Note that for certain keys you can't supply two options, but I don't think those are keys that you would want to vary.

[image: Picture of keybindings]

Comment: This is actually a pretty good idea. I'll give it a while longer and then accept your answer.